# Notification of phone call or txt message on iPhone or Android

Tags: android, ios, iphone

Can an app running on an iPhone or Android phone know when a user sends a txt or makes a phone call? Much like apps get notified of location/gps changes can apps get notified of voice and txt changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In iOS: No, you cannot monitorize events in the phone outside of your app.

In Android: Yes, you can create a broadcast receiver and register your app like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReciever">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter>
```